# How to redirect if form isValid()?

Tags: symfony

How to redirect if form isValid?

This code makes form never valid and click submit just reload form page.

1.

```
/**
 * @Route("/a", name="a")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function aAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Ksiazka:a.html.twig', array());
}
```

template `a.html.twig`

```
{% render (controller('AppBundle:Ksiazka:asearch')) %}
```

2.

```
/**
 * @Route("/asearch", name="asearch")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function asearchAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setMethod('GET')
        ->add('input', 'text')
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->get('input')->getData();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('asearch_results', array('ksiazki' => $data)));
    }

    return 
    $this->render('AppBundle:Ksiazka:asearch.html.twig', 
        array('form'   => $form->createView()));
}
```

template `asearch.html.twig`

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

3.

```
/**
 * @Route("/asearch/results/{ksiazki}", name="asearch_results")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function asearchResultsAction(Request $request, $ksiazki=false)
{
    return array( 'entity' => $ksiazki);
}
```

template `asearch_results.html.twig`

```
{{ entity }}
```

Comment: Answer your own question, it could be useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add line `->setAction($this->generateUrl('asearch'))` in `createFormBuilder()`